# How To Setup DNS

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, ubuntu

I have a brand new, dedicated server.

And I am lost, on how to setup the DNS.

Can I use free service like DynDNS, or Xname.

Is it better to install BIND9 and host my self the DNS server. But I think I need 2 DNS servers ( on 2 differents machines?)

I will host multiple website on the server with Apache virtual Host.

Answer (score 4):

Your ISP/collocator should offer some kind of DNS service, ask them.

If you intend to change the record often it may be useful to keep the master DNS server on your own machine and the slave on ISP side. Otherwise you shouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and also let me know the OS you are using...

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bind9-set-vanity-dns-nameserver/

Comment: the OS is in the tag. * Ubuntu 10.04 LTS -Lucid Lynx. Every time was googling around I found new things to confuse me more. Like on your link,  the term Vanity =). Thanks for the link. I will check with my hosting like @Hubert Kario said. I think I will keep it simple and that every sites will use the same name server address.

Comment: Tags are for categorization -- they are not a good way to add information to a question.